# How to trigger one mail for multiple errors

Tags: php, mysql, email, error-handling

I have an MYSQL table as below and it logs database error if any occurred during the program execution. This part works fine.

[image]

Now I'm planning to extend the functionality by triggering a mail if a database error occurred. So I can attend it ASAP.

The issue I'm having is if one error occurs I get one mail. if 100 errors occur I get 100 mails which is useless. What I want to do is get one mail despite of how many errors occur during an hour. Now I just use the PHP mail function to send the mail when I insert data to the table.

Given that I can not write a cron job which sends me a mail once an hour because I want to get the mail right away when the error occurs.

How can I get it done?

Comment: Show code how are you sending emails based on errors??

Comment: I send one mail for each error occurred now. Just PHP mail function.

Comment: Assign each execution something like a queue number? And then only send an email / queue number with errors? I'm guessing it can't be as simple as that...

Comment: Set a time interval between mails so that a new mail will check for all the errors for that time interval and send only a mail with all errors..

Comment: @Coderanonymous how can I do it

Comment: See what you can do is if you do not want to use cron job, as time interval can be achieved only from cron job, on each error check in db if there are more errors in db for the same time the error occured and after that time, if yes attach those errors and send mail, and if mails are already sent for the corresponding error or not, if sent dont send mail again.

Comment: i am assuming that 100 errors occur at the same time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is

DB error has occurred means that It could be a simple error or fatal one such as MySQL server has gone away. Trying to access the database would be useless at that point.

- Create an error log file on the fly.
- If the file size is 0 Bytes/does not exist I trigger an email then log the errors to the newly created file.
- If more errors occur I log them all.
- After attending to the error I clear/delete the file.
- Next time error occurs I get an mail again.

I know it has the one and only manual work of deleting the file. But you solve a lot of problems by using this method.

```
     /**
     * THIS FUNCTION LOGS THE ERRORS TO THE FILE
     * @param  string  $error_details Details of The Error
     * @return bool            
     */
    function saveErrorToFile($error_details){

        $file_path = JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'helpers'.DS.'error_log.txt';
        if(!JFile::exists($file_path ))
        {
            //create the file and write the error
            JFile::write($file_path,$error_details);

            //send the mail with the error
            $mail =& JFactory::getMailer();
            $mail->setSender(array('support@abc.com', 'support'));
            $mail->setSubject('DATABASE ERROR');
            $mail->setBody($error_details);
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->addRecipient('dasun@abc.com');
            $mail->Send();

        }
        else
        {
            //read the existing content of the file and append with the new error
            $file_content = JFile::read($file_path);
            $file_content = $file_content."\n\n".$error_details;
            JFile::write($file_path,$file_content);
        }

        return true;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could alternatively have a flag in the DB table that stores whether that error has been reported by email yet and a datetime the error occurred. decide a time you want to get your email report, for example every hour on the hour. Then when you catch your error and insert it to the DB, check if there is any outstanding  errors to report and if their time timestamp is past your decided time, if so then group them all and email the report.